# Trying to make a .dll plug-in but the debugging through program gives The error

Tags: c++, plugins, dll, visual-studio-2012

Well, as the title says,i'm trying to make a .dll plug-in for a program called "EuroScope.exe". For the first couple of days i was just trying and trying to make one out of the templates(MFC DLL with Regular DLL using shared MFC DLL).

When that failed(i didn't understood why at the time) i tried to follow a Guide to make plug-ins specifically for this program and even though i opened a plug-in from the examples i couldn't start it. If i build and then open the .dll in the program it works but the thing is, i'll need to start it from scratch so i desperately need to debug and test it with the use of breakpoints. And the problem is here, when i debug it through "EuroScope.exe" it says **"Debugging information for 'Euroscope.exe' cannot be found or does not match. Binary was not built with debug information. Do you want to continue debugging? YES NO?"** and the breakpoints say **"The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No symbols have been loaded for this document"**. I've literally searched and done hundreds of solutions to this and nothing works (not the "Re-install Visual Studio" however because personally i hate that solution and because my Visual Studio is working fine in the others areas).

What i expected,and as the Guide says: "It is possible to debug a plug-in. In the project properties dialog specify Euroscope as the command to be executed and then go and load the debug version of your DLL. You will be able to define breakpoints inside your DLL and debug as normal"

I'm getting really down about this because this is for my thesis and because of this problem i'm wasting time and i couldn't even start the plug-in making per se....

Please help me guys

Thank you

P.S: 1 more information about the problem. When debugging(it i click yes to that problem) it says:

```
'EuroScope.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'D:\Thesis\Euroscope\EuroScope.exe'.Module was built without symbols.
EuroScope.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll'.Symbols loaded.
'EuroScope.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\kernel32.dll'.Symbols loaded.
....
....
'EuroScope.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'D:\Thesis\Euroscope\EuroScopePlugInDll.dll'.Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'EuroScope.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\winsxs 22-\x86_microsoft.vc80.mfc_1fc8b
...
```

Do you think these lines have to do with the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output messages you show are normal when you are debugging a program you did not build. They do not indicate errors, only that you cannot set breakpoints in non-debug code.

I assume that EuroScopePlugInDll.dll is your project and it builds successfully. To be able to debug it: (1) Make sure you are building a debug configuration, not a release configuration. (2) Make sure the dll file and the pdb file produced by your build are in the same directory. You probably have to move them to the same directory as EuroScope.exe. With that you should be able to set breakpoints in the dll source code.

Comment: No, EuroScopePlugInDll.dll it's a library with lots of functions given to plug-in makers. I added the EuroscopePlugInDll.lib to the Dependencies and the EuroscopePlugIn.h to the header files of my .dll.

Comment: Well out of luck and with what you said i found a solution i think: I debug and when the program starts i load the .dll of the plug-in into the program(instead of copying it to the same folder of Euroscope.exe). I also copied EuroScopePlugInDll.dll to the same folder of the .lib and .h and added it to the Path of the debugging.
From that point on some of the breakpoins appear to be working(the ones that aren't will probably have some reason not to). 
Thank you very much ScottMcP